# How to convert json value to float javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is my javascript object and code

```
buildingJson: {
    name: "build",
    height: 40
}

var val = parseFloat(buildingJson.height).toFixed(2);
buildingJson.height = val;
console.log(typeof buildingJson.height);
```

This is always logging out a string even though the value is 40.0.

How to set the height to a floating point number in the buildingJson object.

Comment: Your current code has a syntax error at `buildingJson`, even if it would be correct then `buildingJson`  is a JavaScript Object, and not JSON. JSON is a textual representation. And it becomes a string because of `toFixed` [MDN: Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed): `[...]Returns: A string representation of numObj that does not use exponential notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place.[...]`

Comment: Do you know what toFixed() returns? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: note: this is not json format valid ..... should you edit and complete your question?

Comment: If there is an answer that worked you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `toFixed` returns a String (that's how the decimals at the end of the number are preserved.  To fixed is designed to be used for display purposes.

Removing that will do what you want.

```
parseFloat(buildingJson.height)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will accept answer shortly. How can I add zeros at end and still make it a float ? Do a second float parse after toFixed?

Comment: You want to add the zeros for display only right?  Just do that right before you display it.

Comment: @budhavarapuranga Don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` returns a string in the given precision. If you want a float, don't use `toFixed()`. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed